# Eigendecomposition of matrix, eigenvector basis

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following doubt. If some matrix A is diagonalizable it means that I can write A = U(A_D)U^-1, where A_D is the diagonal matrix, and the columns of U are the eigenvectors of A. These eigenvectors verify that A|v> = lambda*|v>. So, I understand that the columns of the matrix U are these |v>. However, we know that some constant,c, times |v> is also an eigenvector with the same eigenvalue, A(c*|v>) = lambda*(c*|v>).

My question is the following: {c*|v_i>; i =1,...,N} is also a basis, so if I put c*|v_i> as columns of the U matrix I can not see clearly that will give me the same result as without the constant c.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

If you multiply each eigenvector $\mathbf{u}_i$ by a non-zero constant $c_i$, the new eigenvector basis is given by the columns of the matrix
\begin{equation}
V = U C = U\ \text{diag}(c_1,\ldots,c_n)
\end{equation}
Then
\begin{equation}
V^{-1}A V = C^{-1}U^{-1}A U C = C^{-1} A_D C = C^{-1} C A_D = A_D
\end{equation}
because the product of diagonal matrices is commutative.